# Opening Paypal Digital Goods lightbox

Tags: javascript, django, paypal, stripe-payments

I would like my customers to use the Paypal digital goods lightbox. I've used the following steps in Python/Django/Javascript to create an order by sending the customer to the Paypal website:

1. Click button.
2. Generate token by calling Paypal's SetExpressCheckout.
3. Create an order for my product by visiting 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=' with the token string from step 2 appended to the URL.

The above shows that I'm generating a token correctly, but I would like to use the lightbox instead in step 3. I've read the Digital Goods Integration Guide, but I don't see how I make the lightbox pop up and feed the token to the lightbox. Other documents lead me to think that Paypal causes the lightbox to show when the token is returned. Is there a basic HTML/Javascript/Python example of how the lightbox is activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to use [Stripe](http://stripe.com) instead. Within 5 minutes I had a working lightbox credit card form. Within an hour I had a working payment solution hooked up, and was registering test transactions to my account.

Edit: I don't know why someone is voting down my answer. While waiting for someone to answer my question I in good faith tried Stripe for the first time. It worked.

Comment: Stripe doesn't answer the question you asked.  That's probably why you were voted down.  You were given a link to a guide that shows you exactly how do you what you were asked, and he gave it to you the same day you asked the question.  Stripe does have simple API, but it's for credit card processing only.  You're going to lose out on sales where people would rather pay with PayPal.  Statistics show conversion rates go up quite a bit when you offer PayPal as a payment option.  Again, the link provided tells you exactly how to do what you originally asked.

Comment: Actually I was relatively confused that I answered the question perfectly fine and received a downvote, too.

Answer (score 1):

We've got a pretty good guide that shows how to use the lightbox with Digital Goods: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG/

Hope this helps,
Tim

Comment: The requested page "/devzone/articles/how-implement-paypal-digital-goods" could not be found.

Comment: Yes, we moved the site over to developer.paypal.com: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG/

Comment: Is there some kind of example script somewhere. can't seem to find anywhere.